# I am trying to convert a time column into datetime but the column looks like this '2020-01-07T22:24:20.000Z'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I scraped data from Twitter and I got my date format as `2020-01-07T22:24:20.000Z`. I need to convert it to datetime format.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date for further information.

Answer (score 3):

We can convert a string to pandas datetime(Timestamp) type using pd.to_datetime method.

```
pd.to_datetime('2020-01-07T22:24:20.000Z')
```

**Output**

```
Timestamp('2020-01-07 22:24:20+0000', tz='UTC')
```

If you have a column which needs to be converted to datetime, then

**Input**

```
df = DataFrame({
    'time':['2020-01-07T22:24:20.000Z', '2020-01-08T22:24:20.000Z']
})

    time
0   2020-01-07T22:24:20.000Z
1   2020-01-08T22:24:20.000Z
```

**Conversion**

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df
```

**Output**

```
    time
0   2020-01-07 22:24:20+00:00
1   2020-01-08 22:24:20+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `datetime` library

```js
import datetime as dt

date = '2020-01-07T22:24:20.000Z'


formatted = dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')
```

Output is `Out[25]: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 7, 22, 24, 20)` Note that the decimals from the seconds and the characters T and Z where inserted in my `strptime()` call

Comment: using a literal `Z` in the parsing directive leads to naive datetime (tzinfo not set to UTC) - which is wrong in my opinion since Z denotes UTC and Python treats naive datetime as *local time*, not UTC.

Answer (score -1):

You need to parse the date first

```
function parseTwitterDate(aDate)
{   
  return new Date(Date.parse(aDate.replace(/( \+)/, ' UTC$1')));
  //sample: Wed Mar 13 09:06:07 +0000 2013 
}
```

Then you can convert it to time

```
console.log(parseTwitterDate('2020-01-07T22:24:20.000Z').getTime());
```

This should return the timestamp, This code for javascript
and hope it will help you